# How to restrict users of Google Dataform from pushing the committed code to the "default branch" instead of the "remote branch"

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, dataform

In my project the user was accidentally able to push the committed code to the **main** branch which is the configured "**default branch**". We use GitHub. Is it possible to disable the **"Push to default branch"** option in Dataform. Can we restrict using GitHub access for the secret key? Please let me know the solution to this problem.

Thanks,
Prem

[image]

If i use GitHub desktop application, i am not able to push the code to the **main **branch directly, but i am able to push the code to the **main **branch in dataform. I have been trying to restrict the access while creating the secret key.